# SNSDestination causing unexpected key error

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns, amazon-ses

When creating a config set event destination for some AWS SES events, I run into this error. Here's the parameters I pass into ses.createConfigurationSetEventDestination():

```
const destinationParams = {
  ConfigurationSetName: instance.id,
  EventDestination: {
    Name: instance.id,
    MatchingEventTypes: ['send', 'reject', 'bounce', 'complaint', 'delivery', 'open', 'click'],
    Enabled: true,
    SNSDestination: {
      TopicARN: topicArn,
    },
  },
};
```

The error I am getting is

```
UnexpectedParameter: Unexpected key 'SNSDestination' found in params.EventDestination
```

The control flow so far is the following:

- ses.createConfigurationSet()
- sns.createTopic() *// creates new TopicArn to be used in:*
- ses.createConfigurationSetEventDestination()

[These are the docs I'm referencing](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/SES.html#createConfigurationSetEventDestination-property)

Comment: I was able to successfully execute `ses.createConfigurationSetEventDestination()` without any issue using node.js sdk which I have added below. Can you add the whole code to narrow down the issue and also add the entire `error` response received.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am improving my previous answer:

I configured node.js sdk and tried to reproduce the issue. I was able to create `ConfigurationSet` and set `EventDestination` successfully.

**Code:**

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.update({region:'us-east-1'});
var ses = new AWS.SES();

/*const params1 = {
  ConfigurationSet: { 
    Name: 'test'
  }
};
ses.createConfigurationSet(params1, function(err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); 
  else     console.log(data);           
}); */

const destinationParams = {
  ConfigurationSetName: 'test',
  EventDestination: {
    Name: 'testevent',
    MatchingEventTypes: ['send', 'reject', 'bounce', 'complaint', 'delivery', 'open', 'click'],
    Enabled: true,
    SNSDestination: {
      TopicARN: 'arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:XXXXXXXXXXX:test',
    },
  },
};
ses.createConfigurationSetEventDestination(destinationParams, function(err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
  else     console.log(data);           // successful response
});
```

**Response:**

```
{ ResponseMetadata: { RequestId: '838b95ae-af35-11e7-a190-c960102424be' } }
```

So there is no issue with node.js sdk.

Comment: Whether the object property is a string or an identifier shouldn't make a difference. I did try it anyway to no avail.

Comment: Even I though it doesn't make a difference at first. But in python api, it makes a difference. It will throw `NameError: name 'SNSDestination' is not defined` if I dont mention it as a string.

Comment: I copied your code almost verbatim and I am still getting the same error. I can generate a configuration set just fine but SNSDestination is still giving me `UnexpectedParameter: Unexpected key 'SNSDestination' found in params.EventDestination`

Comment: I found out the issue is I had to upgrade aws, haha. Thank you for helping!

Comment: Hahaha.. nice.. that is the next logical step to check since there is no issue with your code.

Comment: @AstroBoogie when you said "upgrade aws", do you mean to nodejs sdk? I'm having the same issue and still could not pass this error from CloudFormation...